# Find $dy/dx$ in terms of $x$ and $y$ when $x^2y^3=7x−3y$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find $dy/dx$ in terms of $x$ and $y$ when
$$x^2y^3=7x−3y$$

Not sure how to start here, would be nice with some pointers

Answer (score 2):

**solution 1:**
$$x^2y^3=7x-3y$$
$$\Longrightarrow 2xy^3+x^2\cdot 3y^2\cdot y'=7-3y'$$
$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=y'=\dfrac{7-2xy^3}{3x^2y^2+3}$$

**solution 2:**

let
$$F(x,y)=x^2y^3-7x+3y$$
$$F'_{x}(x,y)=2xy^3-7$$
$$F'_{y}(x,y)=3x^2y^2+3$$
so
$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=-\dfrac{F'_{x}(x,y)}{F'_{y}(x,y)}=\dfrac{7-2xy^3}{3x^2y^2+3}$$

Comment: That's not right math110. The 2x term needs to be multiplied by y^3 (product rule)

Answer (score 1):

I am going to go a little bit further than the previous answer:

$$x^2y^3=7x-3y\,\,(*)$$

Now what does $\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx}$ have to do with this equation? The derivative is concerned with slopes of tangents to curves. Where is the curve here?

Define a curve $\mathcal{C}$ on the plane as follows:
$$(x,y)\in\mathcal{C}\Leftrightarrow x^2y^3=7x-3y.$$
This $\Leftrightarrow$ means 'if and and only if'.

You have seen this idea before; for example you have 
$$(x,y)\text{ on unit circle}\Leftrightarrow x^2+y^2=1.$$

In other words, points on the curve $\mathcal{C}$ satisfy the equation and every coordinate that satisfies the equation is on the curve.

Now if you draw some kind of squigly curve, then as long as the curve is not vertical nearby, then you can put a small circle around any point on the curve and *locally* it looks like the graph of a function $y=y(x)$. This is the [Implicit Function Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem), and roughly says that if you look near a suitable point $(x_1,y_1)$ on the curve you can solve $(*)$ for $y=y(x)$. This allows us to rewrite $(*)$ as
$$x^2[y(x)]^3=7x-3[y(x)],\,\,\,(**)$$
where I use the square brackets just to help us see where to apply the chain rule.

So now we differentiate (**) according to the normal theorems of differentiation such as the sum, product and chain rules. Using the chain rule to differentiate $(\sin x)^3$ we have

$$\frac{d}{dx}(\sin x)^3=3(\sin x)^2\cdot \frac{d}{dx}\sin x.$$

When we look at $[y(x)]^3$ in this light:
$$\frac{d}{dx}[y(x)]^3=3[y(x)]^2\cdot \frac{d}{dx}[y(x)].$$

But what is $\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx}[y(x)]$? Why exactly what we are looking for $\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx}$!

So we differentiate (**) to generate an equation in $x$, $y$ and $\frac{dy}{dx}$ which we can solve for $\frac{dy}{dx}$ in terms of $x$ and $y$:

$$x^2\left(3y^2\frac{dy}{dx}\right)+2xy^3=7-3\frac{dy}{dx}$$
$$\Rightarrow 3x^2y^2\frac{dy}{dx}+3\frac{dy}{dx}=7-2xy^3$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx}(3x^2y^2+3)=7-2xy^3$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{7-2xy^3}{3x^2y^2+3}$$

PS: The reason you can't have the curve going vertical is that a) graphs of functions don't look like that: see [Vertical Line Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_line_test) and b) the slope will tend to infinity and be undefined there like $\tan 90^\circ$.

PPS: Another way to think of these curves is to solve $(*)$ equal to zero:
$$x^2y^3-7x+3y=0.$$
Now this has the form 
$$F(x,y)=0.$$
However $z=F(x,y)$ can be viewed as a function of two variables. The graph of a function of two variables is a *surface*. The points where $F(x,y)=0$ are just the points "at sea-level" and form a 2-dimensional curve.

PPPS:The reason that $\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx}$ depends on $x$ *and* $y$ is that for a single value of $x$ there might be more than one point on the curve --- with not-necessarily equal slopes. Think of the unit circle and $x=0.5$.